# How can i get the value of a created element if its not an input in JS

Tags: javascript

So I created an item name where i display as the name says the item name and same for item money, and then i have a button that i want to get the values of the item name and item money but it gives me 0

```
    // Update table
    var expenseTitle = document.createElement("li");
    expenseTitle.innerText = expenseName.value;
    expenseTitle.classList.add("title-item");
    expenseTitle.id = "item-title";
    table.appendChild(expenseTitle);

    var expenseMoney = document.createElement("li");
    expenseMoney.innerText = expenseAmmount.value + "$";
    expenseMoney.classList.add("value-item");
    table.appendChild(expenseMoney);

    var editBtn = document.createElement("button");
    editBtn.innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>";
    editBtn.classList.add("edit-btn");
    editBtn.onclick = () => {
      // here when i log the expenseTitle value gives me 0
      console.log(expenseTitle.value);
      // same stands for expenseMoney
      console.log(expenseMoney.value);
      expenseTitle.remove();
      expenseMoney.remove();
      editBtn.remove(), deleteBtn.remove();
    };
    table.appendChild(editBtn);
```

Comment: They're not input-like elements, so they don't have `.value`s

Comment: and is there a way so I can get the value?